# How to change value a variable by Mirror?

Tags: swift, reflection

There is a class that this has fields inside it, I wanna by Swift Reflection  to name **Mirror** get all fields and change with new value,
I can get all child of class **name** and **value**

```
let m = Mirror(reflecting: self)
   for item in m.children {
       print("\(item.name) \(item.value)")
}
```

but not to be change value of variable:

```
let m = Mirror(reflecting: self)
   for item in m.children {
       item.value = "new Value"
}
```

and give a error because field is immutable:

> Cannot assign to property: 'item' is a 'let' constant

is there a way for change value by **Mirror** is Swift?

While Java has ability for this job by **Reflection**

## UPDATE

I use `var` in loop and can change value but field of value not changed in class.

```
let m = Mirror(reflecting: self)
   for var item in m.children {
    item.value = "new Value"
}
```

Comment: Wondering this as well. Did you manage to get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. I think it helps to you

```
func toJSON() throws -> Any? {
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)

    guard !mirror.children.isEmpty else { return self }

    var result: [String: Any] = [:]

    for child in mirror.children {
        if let value = child.value as? JSONSerializable {
            if let key = child.label {
                result[key] = try value.toJSON()
            } else {
                throw CouldNotSerializeError.undefinedKey(source: self, type: String(describing: type(of: child.value)))
            }
        } else {
            throw CouldNotSerializeError.noImplementation(source: self, type: String(describing: type(of: child.value)))
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, but not change field of value.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a solution, although I'm yet to use it: [Swift Runtime Library](https://github.com/wickwirew/Runtime)